# php echo dissappears after document write

Tags: php, echo, document

I have a php request which gets validated, if the validation is a success I want it to echo `Good request` else `Bad request`.

Then I get an array from a txt file and I want to show all the data in that array with `document.write`. But each time I write in the document I lose my `echo`. How can I make sure it writes both?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $session = $_SESSION['pass'];
    $post = $_POST['pass'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if($post === $session){
        echo "<p>Good request</p><br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>Bad request</p><br>";
    }
?>
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'myArrays.txt', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                document.write(response[i].username + ' ' + response[i].password + '<br>')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you have any html in your file? http://www.techrepublic.com/article/required-html-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use document.write it overwrites the document content. You can use a `<div>` to print the text file content.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

and in the script you can use like below to print in that div.

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHtml("your content");
```

Comment: thanks, so `document.write` deletes the content of the whole file?

Comment: Yes, After an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.